# How can I fix this syntax to add a class and style to an Html.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, html, css

I was assigned to edit this view so that the `ActionLink` has the class "th.table-headers", and to make an adjustment to the font.  I saw a suggestion to use `@` to distinguish from C#'s use of the term 'class,' and I followed the syntax they used:

```
new {style = "font-size: 
    14pt", @class = "class name" })
```

However, something's wrong because the change is not reflected when I run the program. I tried making the font size huge at first, to make the difference visible; but it seems that the code isn't working. Below is the code in its original context.  `Html.ActionLink` is the part that should be affected.  Can anyone tell me what's going on with it, and how I can adjust so that the `ActionLink` is given a class and style?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Update", new {style = "font-size: 
14pt", @class = "th.table-headers" })
        </th>
```

Comment: `th.table-headers` means an element `<th>` with class `table-headers`. See Tetsuya's comment below

Comment: `@class = "table-headers"` or `<th class="table-headers">` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you guys! I realized that I misunderstood the meaning of table headers, at first.  I thought my team was referring to the headings for each column of data, but now I see table-headers is actually a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__) documentation, it would be better to change it to something like this (Also you don't need `th` in front of your class name, because the `ActionLink` is already inside a `<th>` element):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Name", "Update", null, new { style = "font-size: 14pt", @class = "table-headers" })
```

Comment: This, + no need to use `th` *because* the `ActionLink` is already inside a `<th>` element

Comment: @Rafalon Yes exactly. this is why I recommended to remove it in front of class name.

Comment: I don't really understand why you got downvoted. Okay your first answer wasn't that good, but your edits improved it quite well. I know you recommended this for that reason, I just wanted to make it clear for the OP as he seems to lack some `css` understanding

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help and clarification! I now see I misunderstood "table headers" to be text headings above each column of data, but your explanation made me realize table-headers is a class instead.  I appreciate your guidance and am making the changes now.